# Flask on Ubuntu is unable to find Flask.json

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, virtualenv

I'm working on a web app with a friend. We're using Git, and we're on the same part of the same branch. We're both running the app in a virtualenv, and we've got the same dependencies installed, which we pulled from a requirements file.

All was fine, until of course it wasn't. The following error came about when I added some logic to handle some forms. I'm working on this using a Macbook Pro using OS X 10.8.4 and he is using Ubuntu 12:04LTS. I can run the app with no problems, but when he runs it he gets the following error.

```
from flask.json import dumps, JSONEncoder
ImportError: No module named json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../run.py", line 1, in <module>
  from app import app
  File "/home/nadil/really-scrapable-web-app/app/_init_.py", line 6, in <module>
  from app import views
  File "/home/nadil/really-scrapable-web-app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
  from forms import LoginForm
  File "/home/nadil/really-scrapable-web-app/app/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
  from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, BooleanField
  File "/home/nadil/v/scrapable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/_init_.py", line 16, in <module>
  from .recaptcha import *
  File "/home/nadil/v/scrapable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/_init_.py", line 2, in <module>
  from .fields import *
  File "/home/nadil/v/scrapable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
  from . import widgets
  File "/home/nadil/v/scrapable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py", line 5, in <module>
  from flask.json import dumps, JSONEncoder
ImportError: No module named json
```

The code is located here: https://github.com/matthewhughes/really-scrapable-web-app

We have no idea what is going on. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

It works with an older version of flask-wtf.

First uninstall the current version:

```
pip uninstall flask-wtf
```

Then, install an older version:

```
pip install flask-wtf==0.8.4
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 0.9 json (but it is in 0.10) is not a module. You can use it like this:

```
from flask import json

json.dumps(..)
json.JSONEncoder
```

This is actually a backwards-compatibiliy bug in the `flask-wtf`. This is fixed in the latest version of flask-wtf

See the git diff here:

https://github.com/ajford/flask-wtf/commit/6dea39dd2f130571c0028f1de6e489260fa01d47#flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py

I suggest you both use the latest versions of both `flask-wtf` and `flask` itself.

Comment: I'm using Flask 0.9. I'm just curious as to why my code works in the same Virtualenv with the same packages installed on a Mac, but not on a machine running Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks ever so much! I tried the latest version, but no luck. :(

Comment: Get the latest version from github, it was only changed 16 hours ago, it is unlikely that it is in the latest sources

Answer (score 0):

As far as the actual problem I agree with Uku's answer. Flask-WTF 0.9 and up were changed to support Flask 0.10, and those changes inadvertently broke the support for Flask 0.9. If you downgrade your Flask-WTF to 0.8.4, or upgrade your Flask to 0.10 you will be fine.

Regarding your question about why it works on your Mac but not on your friend's Ubuntu laptop, note that your `requirements.txt` file does not specify exact versions for all packages. If you do a `pip freeze` on each of these computers you will see that the actual versions installed are different. My recommendation is that you add versions to all packages, and then reinstall the virtual environment on both computers. Only then you can be sure the two are 100% aligned.

See my article, [The Package Dependency Blues](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-package-dependency-blues) for some ideas and best practices regarding package dependencies.